# Get compressed size of compressed file with redirect to /dev/null?

Tags: files, pipe, compression

I have a compressed file, and on compression or decompression, I want to get it's final compressed size (for compression) or original compressed size (for decompression).

I have used `wc -c` before:

```
$time xz -fc inputfile.tar | wc -c
1318524
2.132
```

However, the execution time is significantly more since I am still writing file to disk, instead of when I am using redirect to /dev/null:

```
$ time xz -fc inputfile.tar > /dev/null
1.671
```

How do I get compressed size (1318524) with final redirection of data to /dev/null?

Comment: ```xz --verbose``` will print stats (unfortunately human readable format)

Comment: I suspect this may be a pretty bad idea since you'll probably want to run the operation again which will take more resources than the disk speed and usage limitations would save.

Comment: Have you try to use ls after the compression to get size of resulting file?

Comment: `time xz -fc inputfile.tar | wc -c` doesn't write anything to disk...

Comment: It still takes longer to execute. Maybe because it opens another process for wc. I kind of solve my problem by running same command again, first to get time and then CR. But of course its not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `xz` operating on a file, you should make it operate on the stdin stream. This will get you the file size without writing data:

```
cat inputfile.tar | xz -c | wc -c
```